# how spring boot specify multi prefix in ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

I have to use multi datasource in my business e.g.

```
foo.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/foo
foo.datasource.username=root
foo.datasource.password=12345678

bar.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/bar
...
```

but some datasource config could share e.g.

```
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1
```

I want to know if could specify multi `@ConfigurationProperties` e.g.

```
@Bean(name = "fooDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = {"foo.datasource","spring.datasource"})
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

and how?

Comment: did you find a way in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that thing you want to do with multiple `prefix` as you've discovered no doubt.

The easiest would be probably with something like a BeanPostProcessor:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

@Component // or create in a configuration class
public class DataSourceCustomizer implements BeanPostProcessor {

  // .. inject here some shared properties
  // either via @Value annotation or a @ConfigurationProperties 
  // annotated class

  @Override
  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
      // you will have to cast here to a type of your data source
      // by default it will be org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
      DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) bean;
      // .. now set some common properties ..
    }
    return bean;
  }

  @Override
  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    return bean;
  }
}
```